# Add ServerClick event to ASP.NET <button> element

Tags: asp.net, events, event-handling, onclick

I am looking to handle the click event of an HTML `<button>` (not an `<input type="button">`) on the back end. The reason I want to handle a button is because the design I have has button controls all over the place, so to modify all of the CSS would be much more work.

For my button, I have:

```
   <button type="submit" id="submit" runat="server">Send</button>
```

In my code behind, I have:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            submit.ServerClick += new EventHandler(submit_click);
        }
    }

    protected void submit_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // never being hit
    }
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should remove the conditional check for `if (Page.IsPostBack)`. Your code will not currently work because the onclick handler only gets set when the page gets first rendered. Then when the user clicks on the button a postback occurs but now your page code no longer has the handler associated with the button so there is no code to execute. Just do this:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    submit.ServerClick += new EventHandler(submit_click);
}

protected void submit_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // now it should get hit
}
```

Comment: Thank you. It's been a while since I've done webform development so event handling has kinda slipped past me. Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 3):

Another way is to just add it to the button element:

```
<button type="submit" id="submit" runat="server" onserverclick="Button1_OnClick">Send</button>

void Button1_OnClick(object Source, EventArgs e) 
  {
     // Do Something here
  }
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a8fd2268%28v=VS.100%29.aspx